# Can I use Gymnasium with Ray's RLlib?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, ray

I want to develop a custom Reinforcement Learning environment. Previously, I have been working with OpenAI's gym library and Ray's RLlib. I noticed that the README.md in the Open AI's gym library suggests moving to Gymnasium @ (https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Gymnasium). But I have yet to find a statement from Ray on using Gymnasium instead of gym.

**Will I have problems using Gymnasium and Ray's RLlib?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will at the moment. One difference is that when performing an action in gynasium with the `env.step(action)` method, it returns a 5-tuple - the old "done" from gym<0.24.1 has been replaced with two final states - "truncated" or "terminated".

There is an outstanding issue to integrate gymnasium into rllib and I expect this issue will be resolved soon: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/29697